# How to prevent keypress execution in bash on python exit

Tags: python, linux, bash, keyboard

I'm making use of the `keyboard` package to capture key events in a python program. Take this simple script with the following:

```
import keyboard

while True:
    try:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('ESC'):
            break
        else:
            pass
    except:
        break
```

When I run this script in terminal it behaves as expected until the program closes, at which point everything I typed is entered into the bash terminal as shell commands. This could be dangerous, as every line entered has the possibility of creating adverse system effects.

Any suggested workarounds for this? Pure python solutions preferred but script initialization parameters in bash are suitable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a global keyboard hook to read input for a single terminal. This is bad design because it spies on events the user may have meant for other programs, it stops your program from working like a normal terminal program (e.g. it won't run over `ssh`), and since you don't touch your own input queue you will see duplicated input (as you've discovered).

The better solution is to set the tty to raw mode, and keep reading single keypresses until you want to exit

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import termios, tty, sys

# Save terminal settings
old = termios.tcgetattr(0)
# Disable buffering
tty.setcbreak(0)

# Read until Esc
while sys.stdin.read(1) != "\x1B":
  pass

# Set the terminal settings back
termios.tcsetattr(0, termios.TCSANOW, old)
```

If you prefer your design, you can flush the input queue before you exit:

```
import termios
termios.tcflush(0, termios.TCIFLUSH)
```

Comment: I was okay with that tradeoff because it's a PC, but I would like to be able to remote in. Thanks for both answers!

Answer (score 2):

If you are running on linux you can use `exec` to run your program. Using exec makes the program take over the terminal. That way when the program finishes, nothing further can be written to the terminal.

If you're using windows or just want a pure python answer, you can use the following code to do the same thing and exit the program.

```
import os, signal
os.kill(os.getppid(), signal.SIGHUP)
```

Comment: This does work. Only curious bit is that kills the terminal afterwards!